# Disable submit if input text is not in datalist

Tags: javascript, input, submit, datalist

I would like disable this submit button if the text entered in this input is not in `datalist`.

```
<label><h5>Code application</h5></label>
<input
  name="applicationCodeId"
  id="applicationCodeId"
  list="applicationCodeList"
  class="disableAutoComplete"
/>
<datalist id="applicationCodeList">
  <div th:each="applicationCode : ${applicationCodes}">
    <option
      name="applicationCodeId"
      th:text="${applicationCode.applicationCodeName}+ ' : ' +${applicationCode.projectName}"
      th:value="${applicationCode.getId()}"
    ></option>
  </div>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rely on the `disabled` attribute of your submit button/input: update it every time the input content is modified. An option is to use `querySelector` to check if the current text match an option value with the selector `option[value="..."]`. Something like that:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const currentValue = document.getElementById('applicationCodeId').value;
  document.getElementById("mySubmit").disabled =
    currentValue.length === 0 ||
    document.querySelector('option[value="' + currentValue + '"]') === null;
}
```

```html
<label><h5>Code application</h5></label>
<input
  name="applicationCodeId"
  id="applicationCodeId"
  list="applicationCodeList"
  class="disableAutoComplete"
  oninput="myFunction()"
/>
<datalist id="applicationCodeList">
  <option value="Option 1">
  <option value="Option 2">
</datalist>
<input type="submit" id="mySubmit" disabled>
```

Be aware that when using `<datalist>`, the option value takes precedence on the text: you may type the text inside the input, but it will be replaced with the value. That's why the above solution is based on values :)

---

Note that a datalist should only contains `<option>` elements: no `<div>` (see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist#R%C3%A9sum%C3%A9_technique)). The names can also be removed on the options.

Because the solution above works on the value attribute, your code may become:

```
<datalist id="applicationCodeList">
  <option
    th:each="applicationCode : ${applicationCodes}"
    th:value="${applicationCode.applicationCodeName}+ ' : ' +${applicationCode.projectName}"
  >
</datalist>
```

You will have to retrieve the id in server side ;)